# SQL Developer export/import SSH hosts

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

Is it possible to export/import ssh hosts from SQL Developer? The hosts are listed under C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system17.4.0.355.2349\o.sqldeveloper.ssh but I don't find a way to export/import them into a SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way that I have seen or found.  I also pinged Jeff Smith and Kris Rice (Product Owner and Developer for the platform) on Twitter and they confirmed as well.  (see https://twitter.com/thatjeffsmith/status/1125396802423992322)

On the plus side:  You have located the configuration file.  And, while not ideal, at least you can make your configurations somewhat portable.  :-)